# Get value from field outside field collection

Tags: entities

I have the following setup:

- Field price (boolean)
- Field collection

  - Field amount (decimal)
  - Field total (computed)

How can I load the "price" field inside the "total" computed field to calculate with it? When I use my normal code in the total computed field nothing happened, probably because I want to load a field from outside the collection? Anyone has an idea how to achieve this?

```
 $price = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_price')));
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code? What values do $entity_type and $entity have?